# Possible to replace all occurrences of a lower case character in either SSIS or SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, ssis, data-manipulation

For some particular fields, I need to add an underscore after any lower case character. UPPER/LOWER are of no help in this case, but the fact that these functions can pin down which characters are of the wrong case suggests that this should be possible.

Note that I am using SQL Server.

Comment: what version of sql server?  2014, 2016, 2017...?

Comment: @TimMylott Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
 Dec  4 2019 21:24:18 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: Are you looking for a solution using SQL or SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have underscores except for after lowercase letters

```
SELECT REPLACE(fieldName, '_', '')
SELECT REPLACE(fieldName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 'a', 'a_')
SELECT REPLACE(fieldName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 'b', 'b_')
```

Comment: This method would require repeating for every letter in the alphabet wouldn't it...?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunate but it works, and quick enough with some macros or tools to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

*Since the question is tagged with [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis), then I will provide a SSIS solution.*

You can simply use a Script Component within a data flow task and use C# regex.replace() function to achieve that, as example:

*Note that you have to import `System.Text.RegularExpressions` assembly in the Script.*

```
var regex = new Regex("[a-z]", RegexOptions.None);
row.outputcolumn = regex.Replace(row.inputcolumn, m => m + "_");
```

If you need to achieve this using SQL, you can use CLR functions similar to:

- [RegEx in SQL Server for replacing text](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/regex-in-sql-server-for-replacing-text)

Comment: Yes an SSIS solution is preferred. I was just beginning to think that was less possible after looking at the functions available for the Derived Column component, but I did not realize a C# script could accomplish this, I will give this a try tomorrow!